# override flex netconnection call method that uses variable arguments

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, netconnection

I need to override the call method from NetConnection class, the signature of the method is:

```
public function call(command:String, responder:Responder, ...parameters):void
```

How do I override that method?

The following lines didn't work for me.

```
override public function call(command:String, responder:Responder, ...parameters):void
{
    super.call (command, responder, ...parameters);
}

override public function call(command:String, responder:Responder, ...parameters):void
{
    super.call (command, responder, parameters);
}
```

Any clue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

parameters is an optional array, so you need to check if they exist.

```
if(parameters.length > 0) {
  super.call(command, responder, parameters);
}
else {
  super.call(command, responder);
}
```